# Use rsync to compare a remote repository with a local one, but send the differences to another remote repository

Tags: rsync

I want to use `rsync` in a script to compare a remote repository with a local one, but then write the differences to a different remote repository. When I try this I get an error:

```
--compare-dest arg does not exist: user@ip:/path/to/repository
```

I believe that the option `--compare-dest` cannot be used remotely. Is there a solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this directly, but it does seem possible up to a point. I'm not sure I would want this in production code, however, as I have not thoroughly checked how the solution handles incremental changes to existing files where there are differences between local source repository, remote repository, and the remote destination.

1. Create a batch file of changes between the source and the primary remote:

   ```
   rsync -av --only-write-batch /…/batch.diff /…/src/ remoteHost:/…/cmp/
   ```
2. Transfer these differences to the remote destination:

   ```
   ssh remoteHost rsync -av --read-batch - /…/dst/ </…/batch.diff
   ```

Worked example:

```
mkdir -p /tmp/763572/src
ssh remoteHost 'mkdir -p /tmp/763572/cmp /tmp/763572/dst'

date >/tmp/763572/src/date
who >/tmp/763572/src/who
ps >/tmp/763572/src/ps

ssh remoteHost 'date >/tmp/763572/cmp/date'
scp -p /tmp/763572/src/ps remoteHost:/tmp/763572/dst/

rsync -av --only-write-batch /tmp/763572/batch.diff /tmp/763572/src/ remoteHost:/tmp/763572/cmp/
ssh remoteHost rsync -av --read-batch - /tmp/763572/dst/ </tmp/763572/batch.diff
```

You can then compare files in your `src`, `cmp` and `dst` directories.

Comment: je vous ai écris dans une réponse